# ¿Como alinear el alto de objetos con CSS?

Tags: html, css

Nesecito alinear el alto de un boton y una caja de texto...Como puedo hacerlo ?

```css
.round {
        background-color: transparent;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        margin: 0 auto 15px auto;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid silver;
        -moz-border-radius: 8px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
        border-radius: 8px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<div class="pull-right">
    <form method="GET">
        <div style="display: inline-block ;">
            <input type="search" id="contractNumber" name="contractNumber" placeholder="Contract Number" class="round" />
            <input type="image" src="~/images/Lupa.jpg" width="30" height="30" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Ahora se ve asi, deberia estar a la misma altura la caja de texto y la imagen de la lupa ...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elimina los atributos `width="30" height="30"` del segundo `input`

```css
.round {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto 15px auto;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="pull-right">
    <form method="GET">
        <div style="display: inline-block ;">
            <input type="search" id="contractNumber" name="contractNumber" placeholder="Contract Number" class="round" />
            <input type="image" src="~/images/Lupa.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: La imagen se ve del tam año original si le quito el width y el heigh

Comment: Ok, es que no se puede visualizar tu imagen... Puedes jugar con esos atributos para que la imagen se adapte a tu necesidad o en ese caso te recomiendo usar `Font Awesome` el cual trae una gran cantidad de iconos vectoriales que puedes usar para tu proyectos, así no tienes que preocuparte por buscar otras imágenes.

Answer (score 2):

Una cosa que puedes hacer es darle un `vertical-align: middle` al `input` de tipo imagen para que se alinee verticalmente con el medio de la línea. De ese modo se alineará al centro vertical, no importará si la imagen tiene 30x30 o 20x20 o si es más grande y la estás escalando (que parece ser tu caso).

Aquí lo puedes ver funcionando (con una imagen de 300x300 escalada a 30x30):

```css
.round {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto 15px auto;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
}

input[type=image] {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="pull-right">
  <form method="GET">
    <div style="display: inline-block ;">
      <input type="search" id="contractNumber" name="contractNumber" placeholder="Contract Number" class="round" />
      <input type="image" src="https://placehold.it/300x300" width="30" height="30" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```